# Copy object to another object without including other properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have a master object where it contains list of properties and these properties have their attributes. I like to copy these object's properties to a new one but omitting some of its properties.

How do you do this? could this be done using ExpandoObj? Removing the properties should be hundle during runtime because in the UI part there are checkbox on which properties to include. If the property is not checked then it should not be including in the creation of the object.

**Update:** properties have their attributes, `[Workbook(Order = 1)]`, I want this to be copied also as it contains information determining how its value can be translated.

Comment: Is this for some sort of serialization?

Comment: @TheGeneral this is more of exporting data to CSV or Excel, I have an option where users can choose which properties they want to include in the export. We're doing this backend and using reflection.

Comment: Consider using _.NET Reflection_.  _AutoMapper_ can also be used

Comment: In a crude Object copying system - you can loop through each property in the source objects (Reflection), check if Properties Name exists in WhiteListMap (list of props to be copied) and then do assignments. WhiteListeMap is controlled by that Checkbox based UI you talking about.

Comment: **Note** : Most of the larger library's that export *CSVs* and *excel documents* have some sort of configurable *runtime binding* in some degree or another

Comment: To me, the way you've asked this question indicates your approach is wrong. You're creating a CSV, so you should be looking to exclude data from being written to the csv as it is being prepared ("here is an object with 20 properties, write these 10"), not looking to take your 20 property object and create some sort of custom object with 10 properties and saying to your csv writer "write all the data in this custom object"

Comment: Show us some class definitions ...

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, it might be better if you can change your approach.  But of course this is not always possible, sometimes the other object class is in a library that you can't change or don't want to change for example.

A simple (but maybe not very efficient so take care) approach is to serialise and deserialise with JSON.
(I know this is technically abuse, and not necessarily efficient in terms of performance, but it is simple).

```
   //Your master class
   public class Master
   {
       public Boolean Enabled { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
       public string Address1 { get; set; }
       public string Address2 { get; set; }
       public string Address3 { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
       public string Postcode { get; set; }
       public string Country { get; set; }

       public Master ()
       {

       }
   }

 //Your simplified class
 public class Simple
 {
       public Boolean Enabled { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
  
       public Simple()
       {

       }
   }

//Code to transform
Master mstr = new Master() { Address1 = "Castle rose", Address2 = "The street", Address3 = "Done the lane", City = "Ebson on the Hill",
           Country = "UK", Postcode = "NR1 1YT", Enabled = true, Name = "John Jones", Status = "Activated" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mstr);
Simple simp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Simple>(json);
```

This is handy, especially if you are doing a PoC or testing etc. and you want something quick but simple. But a better permanent solution is to have a new Constructor of your Simple Class which would accept a Master as input and only copy the attributes it requires.

Or you could use reflection, which might offer more flexibility but also has a performance overhead, so you have to be careful where and how you use it.